# Finding Kp using log Kp

Tags: equilibrium

I am working through some MIT lecture notes trying to understand adiabatic flame temperature. There is a section in these notes where $K_p$ is calculated for the following reaction at $\pu{1600K}$.

$$\ce{CO + \frac{1}{2}O_2 \rightleftharpoons CO_2}$$

The notes find $K_p$ by using the following values:

@$\pu{1600K}$:

$$\log K_p (\ce{CO}) = 8.234$$
$$\log K_p (\ce{O2}) = 0$$
$$\log K_p (\ce{CO2}) = 12.940$$

$$\log K_p (\text{RXN}) = 12.940-0-8.234=4.706 \implies K_p \approx 5 \times10^4$$

What is the significance of these $\log K_p$ values? I'm confused because I thought that $K_p$ was a value pertaining to a reaction as a whole, not specific reactants. Also, where can I find these values online? My notes pointed me towards https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/, but I am having difficulty finding these $\log K_p$ values in that database. I would appreciate any guidance/intuition you may be able to provide!

Comment: There is use of $K_p$ notation for skin permeability. In that use $\log K_p$ is handy.

Comment: You can check this yourself, but my guess is that the Kp's here are those for the standard formation reactions (i.e., the reaction used to determine the free energy and enthalpy of formation of a compound).  That's why it's zero for O2 (delta G = -RT ln Kp; if ln Kp = 0, then delta G = 0)

Comment: @theorist For CO, Atkins 9th ed. gives $\Delta_\mathrm{f}G^\circ(\ce{CO}) = \pu{-137.17 kJ/mol} \implies -\Delta_\mathrm{f}G^\circ/RT = 10.312$; and $\Delta_\mathrm{f}G^\circ(\ce{CO2}) = \pu{-394.36 kJ/mol} \implies -\Delta_\mathrm{f}G^\circ/RT = 29.646$. Granted, those thermodynamic values are for 298 K.

Answer (score 1):

The $K_p$'s here are those for the standard formation reactions.

If you go to the following link, you will see $\Delta G^o_f$ values for $\ce{CO2(g)}$  and $\ce{CO(g)}$, in $100 \,\mathrm{K}$ increments, up to $1500 \,\mathrm{K}$:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjbt56Z9IbvAhXVjp4KHbD-BS0QFjAJegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2Fbbm%253A978-3-319-41616-8%252F1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3rJgF0nzpqXtq9ML9qvGaV

Thus, doing a simple linear extrapolation to $1600 \,\mathrm{K}$ gives us the following:

$$\Delta G^o_f,\ce{CO_2(g)} = -396.309 \mathrm{\frac{kJ}{mol}}$$

$$\Delta G^o_f, \ce{CO(g)} =  -252.3298 \mathrm{\frac{kJ}{mol}}$$

Solving for $\ln K_p$ (using $\Delta G^o = -RT \ln K_p$) gives:

$$\ln K_p,\ce{CO_2(g)} = 29.7906$$

$$\ln K_p, \ce{CO(g)} = 18.9677$$

Dividing by $\ln(10)$ to convert from the natural logarithm to the base-10 logarithm gives:

$$\log K_p,\ce{CO_2(g)} = 12.940$$

$$\log K_p, \ce{CO(g)} = 8.238$$

[$\Delta G^o_f$ for $\ce{CO(g)}$ changes more rapidly with temperature than that for $\ce{CO2(g)}$, so my extrapolation for the former may have a larger error, which could explain the small discrepancy vs. the value you were given.]

In addition, if you appropriately combine the formation reactions to give the net reaction (as you would for a Hess's Law problem), you will see that you get the supplied equation for $\log K_p$ for the net reaction (I'll leave this as an exercise for you).